# Is it safe to plug the connection end of a capacitor?

Tags: power-supply, power-electronics, electrolytic-capacitor

I need to put a capacitor between my motor power supply and ground cables, and have covered the connection with resin for safety. Is it safe to do this?

It's an aluminium electrolytic capacitor by the way.

Many thanks for the help!

Oli[image: Potted capacitor]

Comment: "for safety" - what do you think is safer with this?

Comment: @pipe It's to protect the open wires which could be supplying up to 200W - granted its a bit dodgy at the moment with one soldered connection sticking out - will add another blob of resin - is that what you mean?

Comment: If you have covered the pressure release vent with resin, and run the capacitor hot enough to build up excessive internal pressure, how do you think it will release now?

Comment: @Brian Drummond it's the other end I've covered, cheers

Comment: Presumably we're only talking about 12 volts here so dunno if it's much more "safe"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As long as you're using a non conductive resin and the cap is kept in a safe position to avoid wire breakages or other problems then it should be safe. That being said, if you're planning on using this for anything that would require to pass any safety codes or anything that by itself would not be sufficient, but for hobby/personal type stuff there should be no problem.